# Using multiple references to construct values in YAML

Tags: yaml

I'm wondering if it is possible to use multiple references (*) when constructing a list ?

```
List1 : &l1
 - a
 - b

List2 : &l2
 - c
 - d

List3 : &l3
 - e
 - f

List4 :
 *l1

List5 :
 *l2
 *l3
```

In the above example, the YAML is invalid because
[image]

I'd like to create List5 by combining l2 and l3.
I would like create new lists by combining lists, is there a way to achieve this in YAML ?